# Django with Passenger

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost

I'm trying to get a trivial Django project working with Passenger on Dreamhost, following the instructions  [here](http://www.soasi.com/2008/09/django-10-on-dreamhost-with-passenger-mod_rails/)

I've set up the directories exactly as in that tutorial, and ensured that django is on my PYTHONPATH (I can run python and type 'import django' without any errors).  However, when I try to access the url in a browser, I get the following message: "An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py".  Here is the contents of my  passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append("/path/to/web/root/") # I used the actual path in my file
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = ‘myproject.settings’
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

However, when I put the following simple "Hello World" application in passenger_wsgi.py, it works as intended, suggesting Passenger is set up correctly:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    write = start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ["Hello, world!"]
```

What am I missing?  Seems like some config issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are those fancy quotation marks also in your code?

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = ‘myproject.settings’
                                       ^                  ^
```

If so, start by fixing them, as they cause a syntax error.

Comment: Should I have made this a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!  Wow, I can't believe I made such a silly mistake.  I just copied & pasted that from the tutorial site, and I guess the fancy quotes got copied along with it.

Comment: This is why auto-smart-quotes must DIE!